# Conditional validation message for validates_uniqueness_of

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, conditional-statements

I have the following validation:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  validates :email, uniqueness: { message: "Email already associated with an account" }
...
end
```

My class `User` as a boolean attribute called `active`, and I would like to incorporate it into the validation logic using conditional. What is the best way to throw a custom validation error message if the conditional `user.active? == false`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validations can be represented as instance methods. For example, I have a `Student` model with `first_name` and `last_name` attributes. I want to introduce a validation, which will throw custom errors when either one, or both of the names are empty. I can do this by:

calling the custom method in `validate`:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  validate :full_name_validation, on: :create
...
end
```

and adding my `full_name_validation` method:

```
  def full_name_validation
    if first_name.blank? && last_name.blank?
      errors.add(:full_name, 'Full name is required')
    elsif first_name.blank?
      errors.add(:full_name, 'First name is required')
    else
      errors.add(:full_name, 'Last name is required')
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 3):

I would try adding the following two validations:

`validates :email, uniqueness: { message: "message 1", if: 'active?' }
 validates :email, uniqueness: { message: "message 2", if: '!active?' }`